# Bootstrap block grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have datablocks of 225px by 225px with a 5px padding.

- On 320 px width I want 1 datablock
- on 480px i want 2 datablocks
- on 720px i want 3 datablocks
- on 950px i want 4 datablocks
- on 1175px i want 5 datablocks
- on 1410px i want 6 datablocks

I tried to do this like:

```
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-7"><img src="image/test.png"/></li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-7"><img src="image/test.png"/></li>
```

but I don't have enough possibilities for that. How can I add more or how can I fix it a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly that can't all be done on Bootstrap, your number of columns needs to be a factor of 12, e.g. 5 does not fit into 12 with no remainder. 2, 3, 4 and 6 are OK

Bootstrap also only has 4 cut off points:

- less than 768
- more than or equal to 768
- more than or equal to 992
- more than or equal to 1200

col-xs-12 will mean that when the screen size is 767px and lower, it will take up all 12 columns, so giving you 1 datablock

col-xs-6 will mean than when the screen size is 767px and lower, it will take up 6 columns each, so giving you 2 datablocks per row

col-sm-4 will mean when the screen size is 768 and above, it will take up 4 columns each, giving you 3 per row

col-md-3 will mean when the screen size is 992 and above, it will take up 3 columns each, giving you 4 per row

and

col-lg-2 will mean when the screen is above 1200 each it will take up 2 columns, giving you 6 per row

Answer (score 0):

You can create data blocks divisible by ten using additional classes. Example:
5 blocks per row on screens larger than 1200px:

```
// in your stylesheet
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-xl-2.ten-column {
        width: 20%;
    }
  }


// in page body
<div class="col-xl-2 ten-column"></div>
<div class="col-xl-2 ten-column"></div>
<div class="col-xl-2 ten-column"></div>
<div class="col-xl-2 ten-column"></div>
<div class="col-xl-2 ten-column"></div>
```

Make sure that you do this using additional classes. Do NOT do
    `.col-xs-2 { width: 20%}`

because then if you need to alter the width anywhere else in the page you have to override it with `!important` tags and things get messy fast.